# Cannot open source file "glew.h" and "freeglut.h"

Tags: c++

I am trying to run a project and I have to first include glew.h and freeglut.h. I open Visual Studio, go to Project - > Properties ->c++->General -> Additional Include Directories I write "C:\Users\malvi\Desktop\DevOgl\Common\glew\include\GL;C:\Users\malvi\Desktop\DevOgl\Common\freeglut\include\GL", which are the absolute paths of the glew.h and freeglut.h files, but when I try to run it, it says E1696 "cannot open source file glew.h" and E1696 "cannot open source file freeglut.h". At solution explorer I have algebra.cpp,main.cpp and mesh.cpp under source files and algebra.h,mesh.h and shaders.h under header files.

Any idea what might be going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Did you change the include directories for both Debug/Release as well as the platform options?

Comment: I changed the include directories for Release as that is what I will be using.

Comment: If you quoted like it is seen in the question that is your problem. The following will be seen as a single folder (even though it is invalid in windows): `"C:\Users\malvi\Desktop\DevOgl\Common\glew\include\GL;C:\Users\malvi\Desktop\DevOgl\Common\freeglut\include\GL"`

Comment: Any idea on how to write it? @drescherjm

Comment: Don't put quotes around 2 separate paths. The quotes mean treat everything between the quotes as a single folder. You only need to use quotes if you have a space in the path.  I always advise against setting up your folders that way.